# set localstorage items inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set some items to localstorage via a loop. Here is my code:

```
var catArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cat'));

for (var i = 0, len = catArr.length; i < len; i++) {
              catname = catArr[i]['name'];
           //  alert (catname);
             catdata = [];

            $.ajax({
                  url : "<?php echo site_url("sales/get_cat"); ?>",
                  data : "GET",
                  dataType : "json",
                  success : function(data){
                       for(var x in data){
                           catdata.push(data[x]);
                           localStorage.setItem(catname,JSON.stringify(catdata));
                        }
                  }

                 });
}
```

the cat in localstorage:

```
[{"name":"Beverages","id":"12"},{"name":"Desserts","id":"13"}]
```

The problem is that it is only setting Desserts in the localstorage, but not Beverages as I expected. I tried setting async to false without any success.

Comment: AJAX runs asynchronously. So all the callback functions run at the end of the loop, and `catname` has the value from the last iteration.

Comment: so how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: See the duplicate question I linked to, it shows how to preserve the `catname` variable in the closure.